# Whats the difference between tab and tab widget

Tags: android

I am wondering which one refers to the list of tabs titles at the top of the screen and which refers to the content? I always thought that the widget is the list of titles and tab is the actual content of one tab.
The reason I am confused is because apperently, getCurrentTabview.setBackgroundColor sets the color of one of of the items in the list (the top portion).
But getWidget().geChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor set the color of the whole content.

Sooooo. kinda got confused. any help?

Comment: A Widget is any UI Component. A tab is a widget. 
Paste your code so we can see whats going on.

Answer (score 5):

i believe you are talking about *TabHost* and *TabWidget*:

well, **Tabhost** is the parent container which defines tab+content views. As it's name explains, it hosts the entire view. However, **TabWidget** is the view which offers *tab-buttons* for the tab. Another, third thing, is called **FrameLayout** which offers the place for content(s) to reside

Comment: Thank you. If tabwidget is what offers the button then why does tabwidget.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor changes the color of the whole tab (button and content), not just tab button? It is widget, right? Thanks

Comment: very concise explanation .. like it